# JFrame.setBackground() not working -- why?

Tags: java, swing

```
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setSize(100, 100);
    mainFrame.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
```

My intent is to create a window with a cyan background. What is wrong with this? My window doesn't get cyan, as I'd expect!

Also, could anyone point out why I seem to have all the colors in duplicate (there's a Color.CYAN and a Color.cyan). Is there any difference at all between the two? Maybe the older one was a constant from before there were enums in Java and the second one is from the Enum?

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Why is the windows not cyan as expected?**

The issue here is that the area where the contents of the `JFrame` is being displayed is actually the "content pane", and not contents of the `JFrame` itself.

Therefore, the following line:

```
mainFrame.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
```

Is changing the color of the `JFrame`, but that is actually not the part which is immediately visible when the `JFrame` is displayed.

What is needed is to change the color of what is called the "content pane* (please refer to [How to Use Root Panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for an illustration), by changing the above line to the following:

```
mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
```

Using Frames in Swing could be surprisingly unintuitive at the beginning, so I would strongly recommend taking a look at the resources I've listed at the bottom of this answer.

**Is there a difference between `Color.CYAN` and `Color.cyan`?**

No, there is no difference between the two -- they are both constants in the [`Color`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class which are `Color` objects themselves. The only difference is in the names of the constants.

The constants with lowercase names were introduced when the `Color` class was introduced (which appears to be JDK 1.0, as there is no "Since" notation in the Java API Specification for the `Color` class), and the uppercase names were added later on in JDK 1.4.

Probably the addition of the uppercase named constants were added to make the constant names in the `Color` class consistent with the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConvTOC.doc.html) which in [Section 9: Naming Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html#367) state that constants should be in all uppercase letters.

**Resources**

For more information on how to use Frames, the following resources from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) would be of interest:

- [How to Make Frames](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) - information on general about how to make Frames.
- [How to Use Root Panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) - more specific information about panes, including an illustration of how the different panes relate to each other.
- [Using Top-Level Containers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
mainFrame.setSize(100, 100);
mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
mainFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: its worth noting why it works, not just a code answer. There are multiple panes on the JFrame: root pane, layered pane, content pane, glass pane. The one focused here is the content pane which displays pretty much everything (except the optional menu bar). As of Java 5, most things added directly to the Frame are added to the content pane. However, setting the background color is actually setting the background color of the not visible root pane. Thus you have to get access to the content pane to change the color because theoretically you could change the background color of the other panes.

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the color of the JFrame's content pane.

Other than name there's no difference between the upper and camel case color constants.

Comment: About upper and camal case color constants, yes, that is what I thought. But if there is no difference, why do they exist in duplicate?

Comment: i believe the camelcase names where there first, Not completely sure, but i believe it was just a case of not fitting Sun's naming standards, and so they added the properly capitalized ones to fit the standard. -- and of course they didn't want to remove the camelcased ones because that would break existing programs.