# Java setBackground() confusion

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I'm new to the Java swing library and I'm currently having some trouble setting the background of my JFrame.

I have read [jframe-setbackground-not-working-why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742270/jframe-setbackground-not-working-why) and the link inside it, but it doesn't seem to fit here.

Here is my codes:

```
public class Board extends JPanel{

    public enum pointType{
        EMPTY,
        CARRIER,
        BALL;
    }

    private class Point{
        int x;
        int y;
        pointType type;

        public void paint (Graphics2D g2){
            // color changes depends on pointType
            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2.fillOval(x,y,25,25);
        }
    }

    Point[][] myBoard;

    public Board(){
        //constructor, myBoard = 2d List of points
    }

    //.. other methods and class variables

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for(int k =HEIGHT; k>=0; k--){
            for(int i=WIDTH; i>=0; i--){
                // call paint method for each points on board
                myBoard[i][k].print(g2);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Board board = new Board();
        JFrame myFrame = new Jframe("Game");

        myFrame.add(board);
        board.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

        mtFrane.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
}
```

My code successfully prints all the points according to their pointType, but the board color is not set correctly (still default background).

So here are the questions:

1) How should I set the background correctly?

2) I feel that my code is not using JPanels/JFrames/Graphics together correctly, if   that's the case, any suggestions on how I improve my code structures?

Comment: No, please be careful -- it is `paintComponent(Graphics g)` not `paintComponents` -- ***without*** the trailing `s`

Comment: To set the JPanel's background, call `setBackground(Color c)` in its constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`

```
public class Board extends JPanel{
     @Override
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ...
    }
}
```

For more info have a look at below posts:

- [Difference between paint() and paintcomponent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103553/difference-between-paint-and-paintcomponent)
- [paint() vs. paintComponent(): A Resolution](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/867/entry-2264-paint-vs-paintcomponent-a-resolution/)

[image]

Comment: I was updating my post. Can your wait for a second.

Comment: ***Again***, it is paintComponent not paintComponents! This is a significant error.

Comment: @user1948847 for your information `Point` class doesn't have any `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels These method are too similar. AGAIN I did the mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default `paintComponent()` method in `JPanel` uses the background color stored in the `JPanel`'s instance variable; however, your overridden `paintComponent()` method doesn't make use of the instance variable and so changing it with `setBackground()` won't do anything.

If you want to stick with overriding the `paintComponent()` method, you should draw a box filling the entire area of the `JPanel` with the color which you want inside the `paintComponent()` method.

The new `paintComponent()` method for `Board` would look like this:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // Fill in background

    // Do everything else
    for(int k =HEIGHT; k>=0; k--){
        for(int i=WIDTH; i>=0; i--){
            // call paint method for each points on board
            myBoard[i][k].print(g2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this application, it looks like the user doesn't plan to add any components to the `JPanel`; updated post.

Comment: I just updated `paint(Graphics)` to `paintComponent(Graphics`).

Comment: Now please change the super method call.

Comment: Why `super.paint(g);` is there?

Comment: @APerson Thanks for clearing the behavior of the paint() method