# Error when trying to change the background color using java

Tags: java, swing, colors, awt, background-color

I'm trying this code in Java to start creating a game.I have a problem with the background color which stays by default even though I've used setBackgroundColor into the code.Can someone show me how to fix this?This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class Background extends JFrame{ 

    private JButton b;
     public Background () {

         super("the title");
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

         b=new JButton("ROLL THE DICES");

         b.setForeground(Color.WHITE);//ndryshon ngjyren e shkrimit
         b.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
         b.setBounds(20, 30, 20, 70);
         add(b);

         thehandler hand=new thehandler();
         b.addActionListener(hand);
          }
     private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ju shtypet butonin");

     }

     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {



            Background f=new Background();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            f.setSize(400,300);
            f.setVisible(true);
     }}
```

Comment: @A. Di Matteo what's the problem with the title?That's how I want to name it.

Comment: That's weird, I only added tags, I didn't change the title, you can revert it back, definitely. The history however points at the change as part of my edit, really weird behavior

Comment: Ok! Just thought that was a problem with naming the title like I did.Thought that was a coding problem.Ok thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
f.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
```

to

```
f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
```

You need to change the content pane background.

You can read more about it in here:
[JFrame.setBackground() not working -- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742270/jframe-setbackground-not-working-why)